# My texture's transparency is shown black

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to draw an image on to the screen. My image is drawn correctly but the background color which is transparent is shown **black**.

Why is this so?

My Code:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Position + origin, SourceRect, Color.White * Alpha, 0.0f, origin, Scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
```

Comment: There's not enough information to answer the question here.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Begin method of the SpriteBatch class:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.begin.aspx

It is possible you set the BlendState to something that would ignore the alpha value of the texture.

To check if the Content Processor correctly imports the alpha values of your texture, try to run this code, the pixel at 0, 0 being a transparent pixel:

```
Color[] tData = null;
texture.GetData<Color>(tData);
Debug.Print(tData[0].ToString());
```

texture being the Texture2D you loaded from a ContentManager.